# Metro style apps in app search with suggestions

Tags: c#, search, microsoft-metro

I'm working on a metro app that has an in app search, but it has a lot of results.

I wan't to know how to implement smoothly the load of the results.

I've used the sample on the XAML data binding, which loads a gridview asynchronously, and it works...

but as I start typing, it seems the perform so many queries that breaks...

I need some mechanism to reduce those searches... or make it more fluid for the user...

Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score -1):

Surely you application doesn't have enough screen space to render all the results? I would simply take the first 100 results and just render these.

Comment: That is not my problem, my problem is that my searches perform so fast that each time the user inserts a letter in my textbox it search and fills the listview... if the user types a 10 letter words, it performs 10 searches and starts showing 10 result sets one after the other, which looks akward. I want to know some mechanism to stop the current search.